# How to ignore/comment out a text passage?

Tags: macros

I want to hide a very long LaTeX input text in one passage. If I use  %  for every line I need too much time to hide all the lines. Is there a command that can hide the text in one single passage?

Comment: I think you are looking for package `comment`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some editors have a shortcut for inserting a % in every line of a marked text part. Apart from specific packages you could just define a simple command that throws away its argument (doesn't use it for something), like the following:

```
\long\def\comment#1{}
```

You can then insert it at the beginning of your text passage and add the closing bracket at the end.

```
\comment{
   Text ...
}
```

Comment: Perfect! There are some possibilities that the latex input become gray also? Like when I use % ?

Comment: Since this is an editor specific highlighting feature: no. At least not if you are using this solution. If you use the shortcut (Ctrl+T in TeXmaker & TeXstudio) then every line will be gray with a leading % sign.

Comment: Teah!   ''  Ctrl+T '' is the solution. Thank you :*

Comment: FIY Ctrl+U should uncomment a marked part